# Laravel Sail unable to connect to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

Bit of an odd one, I have 2 projects which are the same but different versions as one is quite old and another is newer but has much less features.
Sail was running fine on the newer one however when installed on the 2nd both stopped being able to communicate with the MySQL DB on the Sail docker container.
I can however connect to the MySQL DB using MySQL workbench and PHP running on the host machine so I'm not sure exactly where the conflict is, has anyone had this issue previously?
I do not have MySQL Server installed on the host
Laravel version: 10.45.1
Sail version: 1.28
Host Machine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQpY.png)
Sail:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KYLG.png)

I have tried reinstalling Laravel sail docker images and sail MySQL
restarting the host machine

Comment: Could be that you already have mysql running when trying to run sail. If you are on linux try sudo systemctl stop mysql and then try to run sail

Comment: Don't paste images of your errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557, although it's awesome that you pasted them on a proper images site. This error `no such file or directory` comes from mixing MySQL versions. In your `docker-compose.yml` file you created a volume for your MySQL data, try to create a new volume with a new directory. Then do the `sail up` thing again. You'll not have the databases from the old data directory, but you might have a working sail by then